# seed method works in local machine but not appharbor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, appharbor, entity-framework-migrations

My seed method works perfectly fine when running in my local machine, but when I push my code to appharbor the seed is not working.

This is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FinalProjectContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;User
Id=user;Password=pass;initial catalog=MyContextDB;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

My seed method is inside the `Configuration` file for migrations:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}

protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
   //add data
}
```

And I'm calling my seed method from the context class, inside the `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>());
}
```

***EDIT***

[image: SQL Server Addon and Settings]

Comment: AppHarbor supports SQLExpress??

Comment: @JayC I don't know, but isn't appharbor supposed to replace my connection string for theirs, and I just have to enter my context name in the sql alias field?

Comment: @SOfanatic I think you need to have the correct connection-name and also setup for the "app/plugin" (whatever AppHarbor calls it) for MSSQL server. Only then will they replace the connection-string. Quick test for this is to try and print `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyContext"].ConnectionString` (using Response.Write or some controller/view).

Comment: @Alxandr, I'll try this and report back, for now I've added a screenshot of the Addon I'm using and its settings.

Comment: @SOfanatic From the start-page (bottom), go here: http://imgur.com/OAbp6mS. You should see connnection-string and a connection-string alias. Try setting the connection-string alias to "MyContext".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, searching, testing and reading, the problem wasn't really related to appharbor per say. The project is using a DBFactory for the context, and this where the problem was occurring. In my local machine EF was calling the Initializer every time I started the application so the Database would get seeded, but in order for this to work in app harbor I had to set the Initializer to false (explicitly) in the DBFactory constructor.

***EDIT***

The problem goes even further. Not sure how EF is tracking this but I think that if I run the code locally then the Database gets created locally and EF flags the migration as "executed", so when I move the code to Appharborit doesn't get seeded. Only way I've found to solve this is to delete the database locally and then push it to Appharbor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your connection-string isn't set by AppHarbor. I'm not entirely sure how to ensure that it does, but if you go to your configuration-page for the MSSQL-"addon" from here:

[image: config variables]

Then set's the "SQLSERVER_CONNECTION_STRING_ALIAS" to your connection-string-name (in your case "MyContext" here:

[image: config-page]

That should probably do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your connectionstring name should be the same as the alias i.e. "FinalProjectContext"

```
<add name="FinalProjectContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;UserId=user;Password=pass;initial catalog=MyContextDB;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then appharbor will know to swap it out for the proper one :)